# Sequences of bounded smooth functions versus numerical sequences of their supremum norms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, smooth-functions

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of smooth functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded together with all their derivatives $f^{(j)}_n$, $j,n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $(\|f_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the corresponding numerical sequence of their supremum norms: $$\|f_n\|_\infty=\sup\{|f_n(t)|\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}\ ,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\ .$$

> **Question:** Can we choose the $f_n$'s so that:
>
> 1. $(\|f_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has *rapid decay*: $(n^k\|f_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *bounded* for *all* $k\in\mathbb{N}$; and
> 2. For each $j\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does *not* have rapid decay but instead only *polynomial growth*: $(n^{-k}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *bounded* for *some* $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Property 2. means that for all (positive) $j\in\mathbb{N}$ there are (positive) $k_+,k_-\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(n^{-k_-}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *bounded* but $(n^{k_+}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *not*. By replacing $k_+,k_-$ with $\max\{k_+,k_-\}$, one can rephrase Property 2. as follows: for all (positive) $j\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a (positive) $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(n^{-k}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *bounded* but $(n^{k}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *not*.

I am particularly interested in specific examples, but abstract (non-)existence arguments are also fine.

**Edit:** in view of the negative answer I have found below, the following weaker situation should prove more interesting:

> **Follow-up question:** Can we choose the $f_n$'s so that:
>
> 1. $(|f_n(t)|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has rapid decay *for each* $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. we *only* require bounds on $(n^k|f_n(t)|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ which are *pointwise in* $t$, and *no longer uniform* as before);
> 2. For *each* $j\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ we have that $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has *polynomial growth*: $(n^{-k}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *bounded* for *some* $k\in\mathbb{N}$; and
> 3. For *some* $j\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ we have that $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does *not* have rapid decay: $(n^k\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *unbounded* for *some* $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

The answer to the follow-up question would be negative if it were somehow possible to use 2) to upgrade the pointwise bounds in 1) to uniform bounds, for if so we are be back to the original question.

Comment: For 1), can't you just take $f_n \equiv 0$ for each $n$

Comment: It's not difficult to come up with examples satisfying either 1) or 2). A non-zero example of 1) would be e.g. the sequence of constant functions $f_n(t)\equiv 2^{-n}$, whereas an example of 2) (which must be non-zero) would be e.g. the sequence of Gaussians $f_n(t)=\exp(-nt^2)$. The first example (as well as yours) violates 2), whereas the second example violates 1). The challenge is to get both 1) and 2) - it may be the case that both requirements cannot even be met simultaneously, I don't know (and would love to)...

Comment: Another example of 1), which actually violates 2) in the opposite direction as the previous ones, would be $f_n(t)=2^{-n}\sin(2^n t)$, whose derivatives have supremum norms which grow exponentially with $n$ from the second derivative onwards.

Comment: Locally, the answer to the follow-up question is *positive*, as suggested in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/478056/52543 - take e.g. $f_n(t)=n^2 t^n(1−t)$, $t\in[0,1]$. Since $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^ k f_n(t)=0$ for all $t\in(0,1)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, 1) holds. 2) is obvious, and the maximum of $f_n(t)$ in $[0,1]$ takes place at the only positive zero $t_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$ of $f'_n(t)=n^3 t^{n−1}(1−\frac{n+1}{n}t)$, with $f_n(t_n)=\frac{n^2}{n+1}(1−\frac{1}{n+1})^n$. Asymptotically we have $f_n(t_n)\sim n/e$ for large $n$ and therefore 3) holds for $j=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is *no* such sequence, due to the following special case of the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality): given any smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded together with all its derivatives, then for all $j,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $j<m$ there is a constant $C=C_{j,m}>0$ such that $$\|f^{(j)}\|_\infty\leq C\|f^{(m)}\|^{\frac{j}{m}}_\infty\|f\|^{1-\frac{j}{m}}_\infty\ .$$ This bound also has a local version: given any $f\in\mathscr{C}^\infty(I)$, $I=[a,b]$ with $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $j,m$ as above, there are constants $C_1=C_{1,j,k}>0$, $C_2=C_{2,j,k}>0$ such that $$\|f^{(j)}\|_{\infty,I}\leq C_1\|f^{(m)}\|^{\frac{j}{m}}_{\infty,I}\|f\|^{1-\frac{j}{m}}_{\infty,I}+C_2\|f\|_{\infty,I}\ ,$$ where $\|f\|_{\infty,I}=\sup\{|f(t)|\ |\ t\in I\}$.

Suppose we are given $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(\|f_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has rapid decay and $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has polynomial growth, that is:

- $(n^k\|f\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for *all* $k\in\mathbb{N}$;
- For all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(n^{-k}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.

The first condition is just 1), whereas the second condition is weaker than 2) in that we do not forbid $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to have rapid decay. We will show now that the latter in fact *must* happen under these two conditions. Given $j<m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k'\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(n^{-k'}\|f^{(m)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, it follows from the first GN inequality that for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$n^k\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty\leq C (n^{-k'}\|f^{(m)}_n\|_\infty)^{\frac{j}{m}}(n^{\frac{mk+jk'}{m-j}}\|f_n\|_\infty)^{1-\frac{j}{m}}$$
and therefore $(n^k\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $j<m\in\mathbb{N}$ were arbitrary, we conclude that 
$(n^k\|f^{(j)}\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for all $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$, as asserted.

It is clear that a local version of this result must also hold: if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of smooth functions on $I=[a,b]$, $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\|f_n\|_{\infty,I})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has rapid decay and $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_{\infty,I})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has polynomial growth, that is:

- $(n^k\|f\|_{\infty,I})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for *all* $k\in\mathbb{N}$;
- For all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(n^{-k}\|f^{(j)}_n\|_{\infty,I})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded,

then $(\|f^{(j)}_n\|_{\infty,I})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ *must also have rapid decay for all* $j\in\mathbb{N}$, for given $j<m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k'\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(n^{-k'}\|f^{(m)}_n\|_{\infty,I})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, it follows from the *second* GN inequality that for all $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$n^k\|f^{(j)}_n\|_{\infty,I}\leq C_1 (n^{-k'}\|f^{(m)}_n\|_{\infty,I})^{\frac{j}{m}}(n^{\frac{mk+jk'}{m-j}}\|f_n\|_{\infty,I})^{1-\frac{j}{m}}+C_2 n^k\|f_n\|_{\infty,I}$$ and therefore $(n^k\|f^{(j)}_n\|_\infty)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for all $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$, as before.